# How to add a class to an element which has a class name not in array

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a "disabled" class to an element which has a class name not in array, and I have an array output like this :

```
["xs", "xl", "s", "m"]
```

and the html markup like this:

```
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size xs" title="xs" data-select="pa_size" data-value="xs">XS</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size xl" title="xl" data-select="pa_size" data-value="xl">XL</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size s" title="s" data-select="pa_size" data-value="s">S</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size m" title="m" data-select="pa_size" data-value="m">M</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size l" title="l" data-select="pa_size" data-value="l">L</a>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
if ( $.inArray(val, array) !== -1 ) { ... }
```

or

```
$.each(array, function() { ... }
```

but no luck.

Comment: please show more context for where you are trying to use code shown. We can't help you resolve why without seeing how you are applying it

Comment: @mplungjan not complaining but using `if ( $.inArray(val, array) !== -1 ) {...}` should work in proper context is why i ask

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes we do not know how he got `val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate [multiple class selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) using the array and avoid them using **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** pseudo-class or **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)** method in jQuery.

```js
var classes = ["xs", "xl", "s", "m"];

$('a').not(classes.map(function(v) {
  // iterate and add `.` before each element
  return '.' + v; 
  // join using `,` to act them as multi selector
}).join(',')).addClass('class')
```

```css
.class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size xs" title="xs" data-select="pa_size" data-value="xs">XS</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size xl" title="xl" data-select="pa_size" data-value="xl">XL</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size s" title="s" data-select="pa_size" data-value="s">S</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size m" title="m" data-select="pa_size" data-value="m">M</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size l" title="l" data-select="pa_size" data-value="l">L</a>
```

---

Or even more simpler as ***@charlietfl*** suggested

```js
var classes = ["xs", "xl", "s", "m"];

$('a').not('.' + classes.join(',.')).addClass('class')
```

```css
.class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size xs" title="xs" data-select="pa_size" data-value="xs">XS</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size xl" title="xl" data-select="pa_size" data-value="xl">XL</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size s" title="s" data-select="pa_size" data-value="s">S</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size m" title="m" data-select="pa_size" data-value="m">M</a>
<a href="js:;" class="pa_size l" title="l" data-select="pa_size" data-value="l">L</a>
```

Comment: Even simpler `$('a').not('.' + classes.join(',.'))`

Comment: @charlietfl - even better for this example. I do like the map too though

Comment: @TommyPradana : use `removeClass('disabled')`

Comment: @TommyPradana : if you like to combine with them then use `$('a').not('.' + classes.join(',.') + '.disabled').addClass('class')`

Comment: Thanks for all, :)

Comment: @TommyPradana : glad to help you :)